# Disabling form default behavior rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to disable my default form behavior. I know typically to do this I am supposed to return false but that is not working. Does disabling default behavior only work after making a post request? I want to disable it because

**A) I want to see if my values are being serialized correctly.**

**B) I want to make a server request in the future without using post, but rather by using websockets**

Current code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".attack").submit(function() {
    var values = $(this).serialize();
    console.log(values);
    return false;
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: remove `return false;` from document ready handler that's not required. Also, What did you got in console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the CSS selector ".attack" applies to the form? Returning false is the right way of disabling the default behavior in this case, [as you can see here](http://jsfiddle.net/4cb9ctb7/1/).

Maybe ".attack" applies to your button? If that's the case, you can use `$(".attack").click` instead (but you still have to return false or receive the event as a parameter and call `event.preventDefault()` before exiting the function).

Comment: You were right, my CSS selector was not detecting the attack class. I had to change my HTML options in my form. Thanks!